# Find the pointwise limit of $\{f_n(x)\}$ where $f_n = \frac{nx}{1+nx^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

Find the pointwise limit of $\{f_n(x)\}$ where $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+nx^2}$. Well, $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{\frac{1}{n}+x^2}$. So isn't the pointwise limit $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$? But when I go to plot, it seems like this really isn't true. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It is true, everywhere except $x=0$.

Comment: Let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n(x)$ be defined as $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+nx^2}$.

Note that $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$.

If $x> 0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \frac1x$.  To show this, let $0< a \le x $.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{nx}{1+nx^2} -\frac1x \right|&= \left|\frac1x \frac{1}{1+nx^2}  \right|\\\\
&\le \frac{1}{na^3}\\\\
&< \epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $n\ge N >\frac{1}{a^3\epsilon}$.  Since $a>0$ is arbitrary, then we have pointwise convergence for $x>0$.  Inasmuch as we also have point-wise convergence for $x=0$ (i.e., $f_n(0)=0$), we now have point-wise convergence for $x\ge 0$.  The case for $x<0$ follows along similar reasoning.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\lim _{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x} & \text{ if } x\not =0\\0 & \text{ for } x=0\end{cases}$$