# Let $f_n(x) = {nx\over 1+nx^2}$ on the domain $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity, sequence-of-function

(a) Find the pointwise limit function $f$ on $[−1, 1]$.

(b) Show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-1}^1 f_n(x)dx$ exists. Is it equal to $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx$?

This is my solution: For part a, I got that the limit of the sequence of the function, is the piecewise function: (Edit, my answer for part a was wrong so I have updated):

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
{1/x},  & \text{if $x$ does not equal to 0} \\
0, & \text{if $x = 0$}
\end{cases}$

I am stuck on part b. I am not sure how to show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-1}^1 f_n(x)dx$ exists. Do I show that the derivative of the $f_n(x)$ exists and its continuous of $[-1,1]$?

As for the second part of the question "is it equal to $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx$?". By the integration and uniform limit theorem, since $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ on [a,b], then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-1}^1 f_n(x)dx$ does not equal to $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)dx$? Is the reasoning right?

Comment: Unless there is a typo the pointwise limit is $\frac 1 x$ for $x \neq 0$ and $\int f(x)dx$ does not even exist.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1230653/find-the-pointwise-limit-of-f-nx-where-f-n-fracnx1nx2 for the limit.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, my bad I did it the other way round so I updated my answer for part a. But I am struggling to show the first half of part b, the integral of the $f_n(x)$

Comment: @ArnaudD. yes, Thank you. I realised the mistake I made for part a.

Comment: For the integral, note that each function $f_n$ is odd.

Comment: @ArnaudD. ah, so if it is an odd function then the integral will be $0$ right?